# GitHub Runner Reusable workflow report error

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using a reusable workflow, and the calling workflow does not report a failure if the reused workflow fails.

If I were to call the workflow directly, a failure would occur and get reported which is the expected behaviour.

What needs to be done to be able to report a failure in the workflow?

**Calling Workflow**

```yaml
name: Deploy to dev

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy-to-env.yml
    with:
      environment: dev
    secrets: inherit
    continue-on-error: false
```

**Reused Workflow**

```yaml
name: Deploy to Environment

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write
jobs:
  validate:
    runs-on:
      - my-custom-runner
    name: Apply Terraform
    environment:
      name: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    env:
      TF_VAR_environment: dev
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 14
      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.2.3

      - name: Terraform fmt
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check
        continue-on-error: false

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform -chdir=terraform/src init

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: terraform plan
        continue-on-error: false

      - name: Terraform Apply
        id: apply
        run: terraform apply
        continue-on-error: false

      - name: Terraform outputs
        id: outputs
        run: terraform output -json
        continue-on-error: true
```

Comment: Did you try removing the last `continue-on-error: true` (in the reusable workflow) to see what happens when a failure occurs? I believe it may be hiding the other failures here.

Comment: @GuiFalourd yes I tried it with and without, and i still dont get any errors